# Toolbar will not collapse with Scrollview as child of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-scrollview, android-toolbar, coordinator-layout

I am trying to follow the Google Docs on using the CoordinatorLayout but i am having an issue with the ScrollView inside the CoordinatorLayout. Basically, the Toolbar normally would collapse with a RecyclerView or a Listview when scrolling down. Now with a ScrollView it will not collapse.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_View"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/filler"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            />

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` in `CoordinatorLayout`, also works for `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: Or you can `ScrollView` with `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The `ScrollView` does not cooperate with the `CoordinatorLayout`. You have to use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: This actually does answer the question, the toolbar won't collapse because `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't support `ScrollView`, OP can get the requested behavior by switching from `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: @dbugger Why doesn't this answer provide an answer?

Comment: I spent over an hour trying to figure out why it wasn't scrolling properly. Thanks!

Comment: confirmed working - even in nested Fragments which are replaced via supportFragmentManager transaction

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! NestedScrollView also works correctly with the CoordinatorLayout when it's inside a viewpager

Comment: Whenever you see something like this, go directly to Android bug tracker and report a bug. Post it back here, and we'll vote it up. Thousands of developers found this answer (workaround) useful, and yet no issues were reported.

Answer (score 37):

Use NestedScrollView to collapse your scrollview as a child of Coordinator Layout.
Replace your code with this code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_View"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/filler"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can keep the `ScrollView` and add this XML property : `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` so it knows the CoordinatorLayout as a sibling and  keep in mind this property is supported just in **lollipop** version **and above**.

Answer (score 2):

The actual answer should be that `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't work with `ScrollView`, because `ScrollView` is not implementing [NestedScrollingChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) interface. `NestedScrollView` is a `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollingChild` implementation. If you want to learn more about nested scrolling I made a [blog post](https://lab.getbase.com/nested-scrolling-with-coordinatorlayout-on-android/) about it.

Comment: Please post the relevant code from the blog post and how it solves OP's question.

Comment: I just wanted to point out the root cause of the problem. The accepted solution is ok, but doesn't provide the explanation why changing ScrollView with NestedScrollView fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm just saying, your solution might be good, it just needs some code from your part, imagine your blog gets deleted (by whatever reason) then, it might become useless. I'm not that into Android development but I know more or less how Stack Overflow works... Not 100% necessary but if you add code to your answer (this and future ones), your Q&A will be much better. It's just a recommendation that if you follow it up I'll be glad to upvote

Answer (score 2):

Use a **`NestedScrollView`** instead of a regular `ScrollView` when using `CoordinatorLayout`.

> To make the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` scroll you can **trigger the scroll
>   behavior** by setting a minimum height of the child Layout of the
>   `NestedScrollView` to *1000dp.
>
> ```
> android:minHeight="1000dp"
> ```

Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!--to trigger scroll behavior-->
    <LinearLayout android:minHeight="1000dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

*SupportDesignDemos example here: https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/SupportDesignDemos/res/layout/include_appbar_scrollview.xml

Comment: It sufficed for me to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on the `NestedScrollView`