# Android: ScrollView vs NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

What is the difference between `ScrollView` and `NestedScrollView`? Both of them, extend `FrameLayout`. I want to know in depth pros and cons of both of them.

Comment: [For vertical scrolling, consider NestedScrollView instead of scroll view which offers greater user interface flexibility and support for the material design scrolling patterns.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 286, accepted):

`NestedScrollView` as the name suggests is used when there is a need for a scrolling view inside another scrolling view. Normally this would be difficult to accomplish since the system would be unable to decide which view to scroll.

This is where `NestedScrollView` comes in.

Comment: Here's a sample App demonstrating a NestedScrollView within a parent ScrollView: https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/NestedScrolling

Answer (score 56):

In addition to the [nested scrolling](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) `NestedScrollView` added one major functionality, which could even make it interesting outside of nested contexts: It has build in support for `OnScrollChangeListener`. Adding a `OnScrollChangeListener` to the original `ScrollView` **below API 23** required subclassing `ScrollView` or [messing around with the `ViewTreeObserver` of the `ScrollView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460126/5021311) which often means even more work than subclassing. With `NestedScrollView` it can be done using the [build-in setter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html#setOnScrollChangeListener(android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener)).

Answer (score 44):

Other than the advantages listed in the answers given, one more advantage of NestedScrollView over ScrollView is its compatibility with CoordinatorLayout. The ScrollView does not cooperate with the CoordinatorLayout. You have to use NestedScrollView to get "scroll off-screen" behaviour for the toolbar.

[Toolbar will not collapse with Scrollview as child of CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645986/toolbar-will-not-collapse-with-scrollview-as-child-of-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: Had to break my head against this issue for many hours. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 22):

**NestedScrollView**

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android.  Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

**ScrollView**

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the
>   user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display.  A
>   ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it
>   containing the entire contents to scroll;  this child may itself be a
>   layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 14):

NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but in NestedScrollView we can put other scrolling views as child of it, e.g. RecyclerView.

But if we put RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, RecyclerView's smooth scrolling is disturbed. So to bring back smooth scrolling there's trick:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

put above line after setting adapter for recyclerView.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this (recyclerView inside a Nested) is quite inefficient in terms of layout passes/measures. Test it and you will see how the RV stops "recycling" views.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini If this is inefficient, is there any better way of doing this ?

Comment: Not with standard Views as far as I know. Possibly now with Compose you can use LazyLists more efficiently, but I haven't had that use-case on me yet.

Answer (score 3):

I think one Benefit of using Nested Scroll view is that the cooridinator layout 
only listens for nested scroll events. So if for ex. you want the toolbar to scroll down when you scroll you content of activity, it will only scroll down when you are using nested scroll view in your layout. If you use a normal scroll view in your layout, the toolbar wont scroll when the user scrolls the content.

Answer (score -1):

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   
 // your Layout xml code


 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31980282)