# scrollview doesnt scroll android studio

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have made several horizontal scrolls within a vertical scroll, the problem is that when executing it on my mobile device it does not scroll down or anything, I would like help since I am very very new to android studio especially in xml, if there is another better way to do it I would like you to help me with this part, anyway thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainRecNotas">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="65dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSecNotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/escribe_la_secuencia"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@string/escribe_la_secuencia"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/puntuacion" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="538dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="464dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
                >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="34dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="34dp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="@string/nota_1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/doN" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/doS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/re" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/reS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mi" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fa" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/faS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sol" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/solS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/la" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/laS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/si" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="34dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="34dp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="@string/nota_2"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/doN" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/doS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/re" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/reS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mi" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fa" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/faS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sol" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/solS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/la" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/laS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/si" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="34dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="34dp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="@string/nota_3"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/doN" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/doS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/re" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/reS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mi" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fa" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/faS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sol" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/solS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/la" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/laS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/si" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="34dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="34dp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="@string/nota_4"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Do" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Do#" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/re" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/reS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mi" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fa" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/faS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sol" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/solS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/la" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/laS" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/si" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottombarr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffff"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffff"
    app:menu="@menu/menu" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Refer to that link an see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773982/android-scrollview-vs-nestedscrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it might not scroll down up is your content doesn't needs scrolling as it fits inside the screen size.For that you can try adding more items or define height for any of the scroll view large enough to make it scrollable.
Other then that it does scroll horizontally for sure.
Also you should try to use `Nested scroll view` that is a much better way as mentioned in the link in the comment.

Comment: When I run it on my cell phone, the last horizontal scrollview with the buttons is not displayed, that is, it is not enough with my screen, but it still does not scroll :(

Comment: I could when I put the last horizontal scroll much lower than the screen with a padding = "255pd", the vertical scroll works but the horizontal scroll that I moved to the bottom stops appearing

Comment: just by adding a height of `500dp` in your last horizontal scroll view instead of `wrap_content` works fine in my emulator. 
It does both horizontal as well as vertical scrolling.